# Calculate area of raster overlap with polygon by raster value, geopandas

Tags: python, geopandas, rasterio, zonal-statistics, jupyter-notebook

I have two inputs, a raster with values ranging between 0-2, and a polygon shapefile.

```
import geopandas as gpd
import xarray as xr
import rasterio
import rioxarray
from rasterstats import zonal_stats

shapefile = gpd.read_file("path/to/shapefile")

raster = rioxarray.open_rasterio("path/to/raster")
```

I want to calculate the area of overlap between the raster and the shapefile, by the assigned to each raster cell. I am trying

```
zs = zonal_stats(shapefile, raster)
```

which returns an error :TypeError: invalid path or file: <xarray.DataArray (band: 1, y: 12225, x: 19350)>
[236553750 values with dtype=uint8]

I want to output a csv, with the area of overlap of each raster value:

```
Value, Area
nodata, Xarea,
0, Xarea,
1, Xarea,
2, Xarea,
```

The raster can be downloaded from : https://www.fs.usda.gov/foresthealth/docs/NIDRM_States/L48.zip  and covers the US, so to test you could use a shapefile within the USA such as an administrative boundary - https://www.igismap.com/california-gis-data-shapefile-administrative-boundary-county-rail-highway/

The raster prints like this in my Jupyter notebook:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try zonal_stats with categorial and count, then multiply by pixel area:

```
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd
from rasterstats import zonal_stats
import rasterio

states = gpd.read_file(r'/home/bera/Downloads/test/tl_2012_us_state/tl_2012_us_state.shp').to_crs("epsg:5070")
raster= r"/home/bera/Downloads/test/L48/L48.tif"

stats = pd.DataFrame(zonal_stats(vectors=states['geometry'], raster=raster, categorical=True, stats='count'))

# stats.head(3) #Total pixel count, and each raster category count

#      count          0         1         2
# 0        0        NaN       NaN       NaN
# 1  1748715  1634168.0   63312.0   51235.0
# 2  1463179  1297149.0   13457.0  152573.0
# 3  2149315  1612216.0  128810.0  408289.0

#Find pixel size
ras = rasterio.open(raster)
a = ras.transform
x, y = abs(a[0]), abs(a[4])
pixelarea = x*y
#pixelarea
#57600.0

stats = stats.fillna(0)*pixelarea/1e6 #Area in sq km per pixel value

result = pd.merge(left=states, right=stats, left_index=True, right_index=True)

# result[['NAME',0,1,2]].head()
#          NAME            0          1           2
# 0      Hawaii       0.0000     0.0000      0.0000
# 1    Arkansas   94128.0768  3646.7712   2951.1360
# 2  New Mexico   74715.7824   775.1232   8788.2048
# 3     Montana   92863.6416  7419.4560  23517.4464
# 4    New York  105927.3216   216.4608   3717.7344
```

[image]